# My 5D III's LCD does not darken when using viewfinder and it stopped providing information, too

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-iii, rear-lcd

I own an EOS 5D Mark III with firmware 1.3.5.

Lately, something went wrong with my settings and I cannot find the solution.

**First problem:** The LCD screen does not turn off when I look through the viewfinder.

**Second problem:** My screen was like this before:

[image: Back of EOS 5D Mark III with Shooting Settings]

but now it is like this:

[image: Back of EOS 5D Mark III with Q-menu]

I want it to be like in the first picture all the time. As it is, I always have to press the `Q` button for this to happen.

Answer (score 3):

### Sometimes, a short look into the [camera's manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/06/eos5d-mk3-im8-en.pdf) is quite helpful. ;-)

---

#### "First problem: the LCD screen does not turn off when I look at it from the viewfinder."

[Pages 19 & 20](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/06/eos5d-mk3-im8-en.pdf#page=19) show the nomenclature of all important parts on the backside of the camera. As you can see, there's no eye sensor. <sub>The light sensor is for the LCD-screen's brightness auto-adjustment.</sub>

[image: EOS 5D Mark III manual - p. 19-20]

<sup>Screenshots from the 5D3's manual (linked above), merged and slightly modified by me.</sup>

---

#### "Second problem: my screen was like this before."

Again, the manual is of help: see [p. 342 -343](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/06/eos5d-mk3-im8-en.pdf#page=342):

> When you press the `INFO`-button while the camera is ready to shoot, you can display [...] Shooting Settings. [...] Under Camera settings<sup>1</sup> tab 3, `INFO button display options` enables you to select the options displayed when the `INFO` button is pressed.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Camera settings: That is the yellow menu with the wrench/spanner as symbol. [(See p. 360)](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/06/eos5d-mk3-im8-en.pdf#page=360)</sub>

Comment: Having been involved in technical documentation and translation, and having been frustrated by some poorly-written manuals, I'd like to offer benefit of the doubt to someone from Turkey, whose native-tongue version of the manual may not be up to par. ;-)

Comment: @LowellMontgomery OP says "I could not figure this out" not "i read manual but can't find relevant setting/info"

Comment: @aaaaaa Even so, I have empathy for someone not figuring out a technical issue, if the camera and/or manual are not in their mother tongue or not translated well for that. I would hesitate to chide someone for not having read the manual.

Comment: @LowellMontgomery StackExhachange philosphy is that OP must show effort and work. Not all of it, but mentioning it is good enough. It is 150% OK to not be proficient at reading english, or just reading any text. It's not OK to google for merely 10 second and come ask question

Comment: @LowellMontgomery I can't prove/refute a poorly written manual. I only know that the GER one is superb - It's one of the few manuals I use in German, not English, because it really makes no difference. But of course, there might be worse ones - and maybe even some alarmingly bad ones. But if the manual said "Please wash your guinea pig to shoot down cameras", I would definitely state that I read the manual & it wasn't helpful at all, that it was confusing, even. Also, the `INFO`-concept is the same on all Canon-DSLRs I know of, so a lot of Turkish people should have that problem in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The Canon 5D Mark III does not have an Eye-Start Sensor, so it won't and can never turn off the LCD by looking at the viewfinder.

The screen show completely different settings. If unsure what you did, you may reset the whole DSLR but you must turn the Mode-Dial to the desired position since that does not get reset.